# Histogram function in python

Tags: python, loops, count, nested, histogram

i Have a set of 100 random distances ranging from 0.5 to 25, most of then only differ between each other by about 0.01 points. I want to create a script that:

1. Reads in a vector with cut off values
   For example the vector for cut off values would be: [ 10.5, 15.2, 17.8 20.1, 24.3]
2. The script would ideally create the bins itself by taking the value before and making it the minimum for the bin and taking the next value in the vector and making it the max

For example:

bin 1 : min =10.50 and the bin max would be 15.2-0.01
bin 2: min=15.2 and the bin max would be 17.8-0.01
bin 3: min- 17.8 and the bin max would be 20.1-0.01
bin 4: min- 20.1 and the bin max would be 24.3-0.1

3. The Script would ideally take the 100 values and sort then into one of the bins so values of 10.8 and 10.99 would be sorted in the bin 1 which is between 10.5 and 15.2. Once the script sorts all 10 values it would return a list with the bin min and max values ( in other words the limits of the bin in this case 10.5 and 15.2) and also return how many numbers of the 100 total fit in the bin.

For example: 
10.51
10.52
10.53 
21.1
21.1

Therefore the histogram loop would run through the numbers on the list and return that bin 1 has 3 values in it and group 2 has 2 numbers in it.

Comment: If the sequence is 10.01 10.02 10.03 11.1 11.11 10.00 10.04 and ranges are the same, will it result in 2 groups or 3?

Comment: It would result in 2 ranges. One with 10.0,10.01,10.02,10.03,10.04 and the other with 11.1 and 11.2

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question. What would be the input of your script? A list of numbers and a list with the ranges? Or should the number of ranges be calculated? What is the expected output? Another list with the histogram values? Do you want a Python base solution or is numpy allowed? What have you tried to achieve your aim, and why did it fail?

Comment: Thank you @Mr.T I have edited my question. Yes i would input one vector which would be a list of numbers and a second vector with the range limits. The expected output is the range and how many numbers fall in that range. I would prefer python as a solution but I am just getting started so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I ask about numpy, because [numpy.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) allows the `bins` parameter to take a list of numbers that define non-uniform bin widths. Maybe you should explore this function, unless you want to write your own script to practice Python coding.